# OpenCV: Is using the same Mat object both as source and destination safe?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I have the following question about OpenCV; I always find the memory management of OpenCV more or less weird and therefore I am not very sure if the following operation is safe (does not cause any dangling pointers, memory leaks etc).

I have a Mat object, storing an image in it and I want to resize it, using the OpenCV function, resize.

I want to use the function as in the following:

```
resize(image,image,Size(),paramStruct.upScaleRatio,paramStruct.upScaleRatio, INTER_LANCZOS4);
```

I am using the source object as the destination as well. How exactly behaves OpenCV in that case, does it safely free the old data in the image object after resizing it (most likely into a temporary object)? Or should I always use a new Mat object, different than the source? (I would not prefer that if possible since it complicates the code)

Comment: No It is not necessary to create a new Mat object every time, This implementation is safe :)

Comment: it is safe but might give worse performance because it might deallocate and allocate new memory more often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It always create new Mat object since one cannot resize in-place. The `image` object can be thought of as an address to `image.data`. When you do

```
image = temp_img
```

it actually only transfers the overheads. So the operation is minimal.

When `temp_imp` is a local variable (like in `resize`) it is freed after the function exits.